# Type casting error in C# lambda expression

Tags: .net, c#-3.0, ilist

I have created an object of `ILIst<Person>`. This list contains objects of type `Person`.
Now I want to filter this list using a lambda expression based on a certain condition. So I did it as follows:

```
IList<Person> personlist = new IList<Person>;
...
...
...

IList<Person> filtered_person = 
        (IList<Person>)personlist.Where(pd => pd.name != "anil");
```

But this line gives error as:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereListIterator`1[Person]' to type 'Person'.
```

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for casting. You can use the [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method to create a list, if you need one:

```
IList<Person> filteredPerson = personlist.Where(pd => pd.name != "anil").ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
IList<Person> filtered_person = (IList<Person>)personlist.Where(pd => pd.name != "anil").ToList();
```

The result of your expression is `IEnumerable<Person>` and needs to be converted to a list.